# how to open my activity from other app

Tags: android, package, launch

I need to open my app from another app (I know the package name)
like this : I want to launch my app when whatsapp launches (whatsapp package is **com.whatsapp** and my package name is **com.example.launcher**).
How can I do this?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer; it is not possible in a practical way as this would be a serious security concern.

What you can do is to use the [AccessbilityService](http://essibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html), ask the user to enable your app for this in the Settings and then listen for when the WhatsApp Activity is resumed.